# Converting a 'long' type into a binary String

Tags: c++, string, binary, data-conversion

My objective is to write an algorithm that would be able to convert a long number into a binary number stored in a string.

Here is my current block of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define LONG_SIZE 64; // size of a long type is 64 bits

using namespace std;

string b10_to_b2(long x)
{
    string binNum;
    if(x < 0) // determine if the number is negative, a number in two's complement will be neg if its' first bit is zero.
    {
            binNum = "1";
    }
    else
    {
            binNum = "0";
    }
    int i = LONG_SIZE - 1;
    while(i > 0)
    {
            i --;
            if( (x & ( 1 << i) ) == ( 1 << i) )
            {
                    binNum = binNum + "1";
            }
            else
            {
                    binNum = binNum + "0";
            }
    }
    return binNum;
}

int main()
{
    cout << b10_to_b2(10) << endl;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
00000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000001010
```

I want the output to be:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010
```

Can anyone identify the problem? For whatever reason the function outputs 10 represented by 32 bits concatenated with another 10 represented by 32 bits.

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::bitset::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string) instead of rolling your own? Otherwise use a debugger 1st to find your bug. Also note to have a guaranteed size of 64 bits you need a `unsigned long long` type.

Comment: You seem to expect to get 32 digits on the output though declare long to be 64 bit long. Can `sizeof` be used instead?

Comment: Maybe your implementation is truncating shifts at modulo 32 bits, so when you shift 33 bits, it actually ends up shifting 1 bit instead? Try using `i` as `long` instead?

Comment: This doesn't compile as you probably intended because you have a trailing semicolon after your macro. Need any more proof why macros are evil? That said, `sizeof x * CHAR_BITS` should give you the amount of bits in `x`.

Comment: IIRC, shifting by more than the bit width even causes undefined behaviour, @MatsPetersson. Common implementations either zero the result or rotate by modulo the bit width. I'm not sure about shifting the actual bit width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why would you assume long is 64 bit?
try `const size_t LONG_SIZE=sizeof(long)*8;`

check this, the program works correctly with my changes
http://ideone.com/y3OeB3

Edit: and ad @Mats Petersson pointed out you can make it more robust by changing this line

`if( (x & ( 1 << i) ) == ( 1 << i) )`

to something like

`if( (x & ( 1UL << i) ) )` where that UL is important, you can see his explanation the the comments

Comment: I suspect this is NOT the problem. Rather that the `1 << i` is performed as `1 << (i % 32)` - because I'm just randomly guessing that the OP is using one of the x86 family of processors.

Comment: maybe, but i have my doubts. http://ideone.com/pkTTZX.
and anyway its still a bad practice

Comment: And assuming you fix this, will the OP's program work? I'd suggest that you at least ALSO need to fix the shift... This given that no matter what size integer we use, `1 << sizeof(T) * 8` should yield `0` - and clearly the OP's code doesn't behave as if that is the case.

Comment: check the edit i made, it works,and i is 63 and `1 << (i % 32)` doesnt make sense, did you mean `(1 << i) % 32`

Comment: And why would you assume a `char` is 8 bit?

Comment: where did char come into picture? I made an assumption that a byte is 8 bits.

Comment: I mean `1 << (i % 32)` - if I meant something else, I would have written something else - try adding `cout << (1 << 33) << endl;` to your code, and see what comes out. Then do `cout << ((uint64_t)(1) << 33) << endl;` and spot the difference.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size in multiples of the size of a `char`, that's where it comes in. Anyhow, why would you assume a byte is an octet? That isn't guaranteed and I have seen platforms where it isn't! BTW: There's a CHAR_BITS constant in some standard header.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt op didnt mention any special cases. and i personally havent seen any platforms where byte is not 8 bits, do let me know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions:

1. Make sure you use a type that is guaranteed to be 64-bit, such as `uint64_t`, `int64_t` or `long long`.
2. Use above mentioned 64-bit type for your variable `i` to guarantee that the `1 << i` calculates correctly. This is caused by the fact that shift is only guaranteed by the standard when the number of bits shifted are less or equal to the number of bits in the type being shifted - and `1` is the type `int`, which for most modern platforms (evidently including yours) is 32 bits.
3. Don't put semicolon on the end of your `#define LONG_SIZE` - or better yet, use `const int long_size = 64;` as this allows all manner of better behaviour, for example that you in the debugger can `print long_size` and get 64, where `print LONG_SIZE` where LONG_SIZE is a macro will yield an error in the debugger.